# How to a convert a listbox item's name to a label in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, label

For the program that I am required to write up, I need the name of a Listbox item to also be the text in the label. This is the code that I thought would work, but it only configurated the label to be the item's number in the Listbox, not the name:

```
def openAccount(self):
    selectedItem = ltboxSrcUser.curselection()
    for item in selectedItem:
        rootMainPage.withdraw()
        rootOthAccPage.deiconify()
        lblOtherUserName.config(text = ltboxSrcUser.curselection())
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you share some more code? Also, ```selectedItem = ltboxSrcUser.ACTIVE (ltboxSrcUser.curselection())```

Comment: Try using `<tkinter.Listbox>.get(<tkinter.Listbox>.curselection())`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the listbox shows that `curselection` returns the *index* of the selected items, not the values. To get the values you must pass the index to the `get` method.

```
def openAccount(self):
    selectedItems = ltboxSrcUser.curselection()
    if selectedItems:
        rootMainPage.withdraw()
        rootOthAccPage.deiconify()
        index = selectedItems[0]
        item = ltboxSrcUser.get(index)
        lblOtherUserName.config(text=item)
```